# java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Commands: [cd, sdcard/.yasmin] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Tags: android

I try to access to my folder in sdcard and install myapp.apk, i use this code:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd sdcard/.yasmin");
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb install tefli.apk");
```

But unfortunatelly i have this error:

```
05-11 11:09:57.925: WARN/System.err(1399): java.io.IOException: 
Error running exec(). Commands: [cd, sdcard/.yasmin] Working Directory: null    Environment: null
```

Anybody please have an idea.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure that this will fix your problem, but AFAIK, each call to `exec()` creates a new shell. A possible solution is to do the following:

1. Get the process of the exec() using: `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`.
2. Grab the process inputStream using `p.getInputStream();`.
3. Run the second command.

also note that you are trying to access the sdcard as you were in root folder and in a hardcoded path, consider the following:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd /sdcard/.yasmin");
```

Or even better:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.yasmin");
```

Hope it'll help!

Comment: Sorry to hear, for both solutions?

Answer (score 6):

you should use 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c cd /sdcard/.yasmin");

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file generated with log as follows:

command - "your command"
Environment - null
Directory - null

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command",null,null);

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Get the process of the exec() using: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...).
> 2. Grab the process inputStream using p.getInputStream();.
> 3. Run the second command.

I would have posted it as a comment to [MByD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464988/mbyd)'s answer but I don't have 50 reputation yet so StackOverflow won't let me.

For the second step you are supposed to use `DataOutputStream` instead of `DataInputStream` to write commands to the shell. `InsputDataStream` is for the opposite purpose in fact that is to read output.

If it sounds confusing then think of it this way:
You are outputting the commands through the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) to the shell hence using `DataOutputStream`. On the other hand you are getting result through the ADB from the shell hence using `DataInputStream`.