# Can't run exec("su") on a rooted Android Marshmallow device, other commands run fine

Tags: android, root, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have gone over all the possible answers to this questions, and none of them has worked for me. Seems like Android has very tightly blocked the running of the shell commands from within an app, even when the device is rooted.

I can do **su** and run commands perfectly fine from **adb**, but I cannot run them from the app itself. It fails with error:

```
Error running exec(). Command: [su]  Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

I have searched for these errors and the solutions work for older versions of Android, not Marshmallow.

I have also tried **libsuperuser** (SuperSu), but it also fails on Marshmallow.

Other things I tried were like, e.g. for the device reboot:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot" });
```

or

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)...
```

Same with other operations. The commands fail right at **su**. I can't issue an **adb** command either from the app. But I can do both perfectly fine otherwise from the command line via adb shell.

The example which Android has on its website doesn't work either.

I read about disabling SELinux security and setting it to permissive mode. But that also require to run **su** first, where the app fails.

Now I am totally lost and don't know what to do next. I am really looking for a working solution since for this particular project, which requires the app to interact with the underlying hardware.

Comment: Hi, have you managed to find a solution for this? I have the same problem...

Comment: No, we couldn't. We gave up on this. There was absolutely no way to run su command from inside an app. Probably if the app is part of the compiled Android build it would work, but that itself is a complex and long process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first ensure you have busybox installed as that would install the list of most commonly used shell commands and then use the following code to run the command.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");

try {
    Process chmod = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/chmod 777 " +fileName);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(nfiq.getInputStream()));

    int read;
    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.append(buffer, 0, read);
    }

    reader.close();
    chmod.waitFor();
    outputString =  output.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: Can BusyBox be distributed as a submodule of an app? The app's APK will be distributed to over a thousand devices (not via Google Play). Its a customized product and we cannot install multiple APKs on it.

Comment: https://github.com/guardianproject/lildebi go through this link if satisfied accept answer as correct

Comment: busybox is not needed for running commands as root. Toolbox and Toybox have `ls` and `chmod`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Process command = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes("-c reboot\n");
dos.writeBytes("exit\n");
dos.flush();
dos.close();
p.waitFor();
```

It can take time to execute so u might wanna run this on worker thread

Comment: The command Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); fails with message Error running exec() . Command: [su]  Working Directory: null Environment: null

Comment: Try this http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572025/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-fails-after-calling-it-several-hundred-times&ei=W8dXmyJb&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=167&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1474080938&sig=AKOVD65C02zBPpL6OGtoanyiFPAGu6hzXw otherwise  maybe your app has some su permission issues or root issues

Comment: Using adb, I can do su and run all the commands. Only through the app, it doesn't work. I have posted my code snippets, and that works on pre-Marshmallow devices just fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I can't seem to su anything on a Marshmallow rooted device either.

Comment: @EdHarcourt try it with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su" });`

Comment: @zeeshan did you find what is a problem? I have same problem as yours.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that blocks shell commands in "Marshmallow" . I am using it inside my app and all commands work flawlessly. There is something else you are missing. First confirm that in your "/system/bin/" directory all files are present. Alternatively check in other device.

Comment: Can you run Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); on a rooted Marshmallow fine? If yes, can you post the code you are running?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "sh -c " as the beginning of your shell command. Otherwise you will get the error message about null directory and environment.

Example: `sh -c su`